# Calling external Javascript from Action Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting a form and would like that, upon validation, my Action method will return a javascript file that lives in Scripts folder.
I have the file's path

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
```

and that is what I have tried (which obviously didn't work)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPerson(Person person)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                return Content("<script src='~/Scripts/MyScript.js'></script>");
            }
            return View(person);
        }
```

How could I do such thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove `~` and change to `return Content("<script src='/Scripts/MyScript.js'></script>");`

I tried to reproduce it can run script in script file.